# How to draw rectangle on touch event

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

How to draw rectangle on touch event in android. I have a canvas when I am touching on the canvas, its drawing a rectangle but when I touch on new location it remove the old rectangle and draw a new rectangle on new location. But, I want to keep all rectangle visible wherever I have touched.

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states

    static final int NONE = 0;

    static final int DRAG = 1;

    static final int ZOOM = 2;

    boolean isCheckLoadImage = false;

    public static boolean isDraw = false;

    int mode = NONE;

    private float mPosX;

    private float mPosY;

    public static int numCell1 = 0;

    public static boolean CorrectTouch;

    float boxHeight, boxWidth;

    // Remember some things for zooming

    PointF last = new PointF();

    PointF start = new PointF();

    float minScale = 1f;

    float maxScale = 6f;

    int lastTouchEvent = -1;

    int selectedCell;

    float[] m;

    float scaleWidth, scaleHeight;

    float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

    float width, height;

    static final int CLICK = 3;

    float saveScale = 1f;

    float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    boolean flag = false;


    public TouchImageView(Context context) {

        super(context);

        sharedConstructing(context);

    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);

        sharedConstructing(context);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

        RectF r = new RectF();

        matrix.mapRect(r);

        boxWidth = scaleWidth / 5;

        boxHeight = scaleHeight / 5;

        float widthOfCell = boxWidth;

        float heightOfCell = boxHeight;

        float[] touchPoint = new float[] { mPosX, mPosY };

        float[] newTouch = new float[] { 0, 0 };

        matrix.mapPoints(newTouch, touchPoint);

        RectF canvasRect = new RectF();

        canvas.getMatrix().mapRect(canvasRect);

        Log.i("canvasRect", "canvasRect.left : " + canvasRect.left
                + " canvasRect.top : " + canvasRect.top);

        Log.i("r", "r.left : " + r.left + " r.top : " + r.top);

        Log.i("Pos", "mPosX : " + mPosX + " mPosY : " + mPosY);

        float newX = mPosX - (r.left);

        float newY = mPosY - (r.top);

        Log.i("new XY", "New X" + newX + " NewY " + newY);

        int myX = (int) (newX / boxWidth); /* Columns */

        int myY = (int) (newY / boxHeight);/* Rows */

        Log.i("my XY", "myX " + myX + " myY " + myY);

        //

        Log.e("GuessImageView", "before grid draw");

        try {

            if (true) {

                if (lastTouchEvent == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    numCell1 = 0;

                    boolean doBreak = false;

                    for (float row = 0; !doBreak
                            && row <5; row++) {

                        float y = (row * heightOfCell) + r.top;

                        for (float col = 0; col < 5; col++) {

                            float x = (col * widthOfCell) + r.left;

                            if ((int) col == myX && (int) row == myY) {

                                canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + widthOfCell, y
                                        + heightOfCell, paint);

                                Log.d("Touch X : " + x, "Touch Y : " + y);

                                selectedCell = numCell1;

                                numCell1++;

                                flag = true;

                                doBreak = true;

                                break;

                            }

                            numCell1++;

                        }

                    }

                    if (flag) {

                        isCheckLoadImage = true;

//                      guessImage.checkForWin(selectedCell);

                    }

                    Log.i("Touch ", "Number Of Cell>" + numCell1);

                    lastTouchEvent = -1;

                }

            }

        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        Log.e("GuessImageView", "after grid draw");

    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {

        super.setClickable(true);

        this.context = context;

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);

        m = new float[9];

        setImageMatrix(matrix);

        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                matrix.getValues(m);

                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];

                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

                    start.set(last);

                    mode = DRAG;

                    // isDraw=false;

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    // Log.i("onTouch", "origWidth : " + origWidth +

                    // " origHeight : " + origHeight);

                    if (mode == DRAG) {

                        // isDraw=false;

                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;

                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;

                        scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);

                        scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);

                        if (scaleWidth < width) {

                            deltaX = 0;

                            if (y + deltaY > 0)

                                deltaY = -y;

                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)

                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);

                        } else if (scaleHeight < height) {

                            deltaY = 0;

                            if (x + deltaX > 0)

                                deltaX = -x;

                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)

                                deltaX = -(x + right);

                        } else {

                            if (x + deltaX > 0)

                                deltaX = -x;

                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)

                                deltaX = -(x + right);

                            if (y + deltaY > 0)

                                deltaY = -y;

                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)

                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);

                        }

                        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);

                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);

                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                    mode = NONE;

                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);

                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);

                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK) {

                        // isDraw=false;

                        Log.v("ACTION_UP", "ACTION_UP");

                        mPosX = curr.x;

                        mPosY = curr.y;

                        performClick();

//                      if (guessImage.guess_mode) {

                            lastTouchEvent = event.getAction();
                        /*}

                        else {

                            lastTouchEvent = -1;

                        }
*/
                        // invalidate();

                    }

                    break;

                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                    mode = NONE;

                    break;

                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);

                scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);

                scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);

                invalidate();

                return true; // indicate event was handled

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {

        super.setImageBitmap(bm);

        if (bm != null) {

            bmWidth = bm.getWidth();

            bmHeight = bm.getHeight();

        }

    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {

        maxScale = x;

    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            mode = ZOOM;

            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

            float origScale = saveScale;

            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;

            if (saveScale > maxScale) {

                saveScale = maxScale;

                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;

            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {

                saveScale = minScale;

                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;

            }

            right = width * saveScale - width
                    - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);

            bottom = height * saveScale - height
                    - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);

            // mPosX = mPosX + right / saveScale;

            // mPosY = mPosY + bottom / saveScale;

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= width
                    || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {

                float xMove = 0, yMove = 0;

                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2,
                        height / 2);

                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {

                    matrix.getValues(m);

                    float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];

                    float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

                    if (mScaleFactor < 1) {

                        if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {

                            if (y < -bottom) {

                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));

                                xMove = 0;

                                yMove = -(y + bottom);

                            } else if (y > 0) {

                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);

                                xMove = 0;

                                yMove = -y;

                            }

                        } else {

                            if (x < -right) {

                                matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);

                                xMove = -(x + right);

                                yMove = 0;

                            } else if (x > 0) {

                                matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);

                                xMove = -(x + right);

                                yMove = 0;

                            }

                        }

                        Log.i("onScale", "mPosX " + mPosX + " mPosX " + mPosX);

                    }

                }

            } else {

                float xMove = 0, yMove = 0;

                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                        detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

                matrix.getValues(m);

                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];

                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {

                    if (x < -right) {

                        matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);

                        xMove = -(x + right);

                        yMove = 0;

                    } else if (x > 0) {

                        matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);

                        xMove = -x;

                        yMove = 0;

                    }

                    if (y < -bottom) {

                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));

                        xMove = 0;

                        yMove = -(y + bottom);

                    } else if (y > 0) {

                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);

                        xMove = 0;

                        yMove = -y;

                    }

                }

                Log.i("onScale", "mPosX " + mPosX + " mPosX " + mPosX);

            }

            return true;

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        if (!isCheckLoadImage) {

            width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

            height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            // Fit to screen.

            float scale;

            float scaleX = (float) width / (float) bmWidth;

            float scaleY = (float) height / (float) bmHeight;

            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            setImageMatrix(matrix);

            saveScale = 1f;

            // Center the image

            redundantYSpace = (float) height - (scale * (float) bmHeight);

            redundantXSpace = (float) width - (scale * (float) bmWidth);

            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;

            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;

            origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;

            right = width * saveScale - width
                    - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);

            bottom = height * saveScale - height
                    - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);

            setImageMatrix(matrix);

        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    }

}
```

Comment: can you show some code what you had done..??

Comment: everytime onDraw is called, the view is drawn again. You will need to store the touch positions in a collection, iterate over it and draw everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store in memory all touch locations and redraw them all each time.

Like in this sample: [Android drawing objects on screen and obtaining geometry data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305706/android-drawing-objects-on-screen-and-obtaining-geometry-data/13308008#13308008)

Answer (score 0):

> This is a section of My code on a Card, I had to draw a rectangle over it and listen the rectangle's click events. The card was for some counting task and the Client for some reason wanted the touch to be extended over the view...

```
 alertCard.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {

        Rect outRect = new Rect();
        alertCard.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);

        // calculate new bottom, to be used for upper part.
        int bottom = (int) (outRect.bottom * 0.95);

        Rect upperRec = new Rect(outRect.left, outRect.top,outRect.right, bottom);

        int value = part.getMistakes().get(0).getValue();

        if (upperRec.contains( (int) event.getRawX(),(int) event.getRawY()))
        {
           //Implement the touch event...

        }

        return false;
    });
```